# Are there any workarounds for CVE-2017-0561 (Broadcom Wi-Fi remote code execution) on Android?

Tags: wifi, android, vulnerability

Google has developed a fix for a critical [remote code execution vulnerability in Broadcom Wi-Fi firmware](https://source.android.com/security/bulletin/2017-04-01#rce-in-broadcom-wi-fi-firmware). There is a [huge amount of information](https://googleprojectzero.blogspot.co.uk/2017/04/over-air-exploiting-broadcoms-wi-fi_4.html) (and possibly [this](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/project-zero/issues/detail?id=1046)) available around it, but as an end user my primary concern is this: **how do I avoid being hacked** while waiting for a patch?

Comment: According to the problem description you should be able to avoid it by switching Wifi off, but that's probably the only reliable workaround.

Comment: To avoid getting compromised keep the Wi-Fi off and make sure it is actually off. Android has a feature where even if Wi-Fi is turned off it will still use it for location and (I'm sure) ad targeting/analytics for Google. This can be disabled as well.

Comment: And as for the vulnerable phones: I don't think you will find a reliable listing of all the phones which both use Broadcom Wi-Fi and have the relevant feature enabled (and that's why I've marked the question as too broad). But if you want to know if your phone is affected contact your vendor.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Alright. I've removed the question about the models.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [detailed report](https://googleprojectzero.blogspot.de/2017/04/over-air-exploiting-broadcoms-wi-fi_4.html) this specific problem can be triggered by specifically constructed Wi-Fi packets. From my understanding this kind of attack should possible for an unauthorized attacker and it does not matter if the victim is associated with a Wi-Fi network or not.  This means that the only workaround to protect a vulnerable device is too completely disable Wi-Fi.